# How do I detect if a remote web page is avaliable

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to check if a web page hosted on a remote server via tomcat is deployed or not.There may be a case where the page is not deployed and I need to capture this.
I've tried with URL connection but I guess that is only useful for verifying if tomcat is up or down on the remote system.

How can I go about verifying whether the page is deployed or not ?

Thanks in advance,
Fell

Comment: Do you need to do the request from inside tomcat? Because if this is about monitoring a website there are probably better solutions then to write your own java program. (So are you monitoring a page hosted on Tomcat, or are you monitoring pages from a Tomcat webapp?)

Comment: Also: the question refers to 'available' but the text refert to 'a valid URL' ... those are quite different.

Comment: Yes.I need to do the request from a java servlet running on tomcat.A different web page is hosted on a remote system and I need to just displat it in my webapp directly.
However there may be the case that tomcat is running on remote system but the required page is not deployed.I need to know when this scenario occurs since it results in a 404 page not found error in my webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLConnection is the way to go. Look at this example http://nadeausoftware.com/node/73

Answer (score 2):

I would use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) and watch for connection and IO exceptions (if the server itself is not responding), and/or the appropriate [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (probably you're only looking for a **200**). I would perhaps issue a HEAD request, rather than a GET request, to simply get the response headers, and not the full page (although this may be an optimisation too far - how expensive is your page to retrieve?) .

You can configure connection timeouts appropriately and thus determine status in a timely fashion.